# Quantum Computing Project Inquiry

Tags: resource-request, research

I am wondering if there is a way to get advice\feedback here about the following: I am about to start a MS physics program. I am interested in quantum computing and my department has the option of pursuing a thesis as a graduation route. I am new to this topic and would like to see if I can get some suggestions - papers, books, topics, etc - to think about to be able to craft a project in quantum computing for a beginner like me that can in a two-year period scale into something with more insight in the topic.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for a place to start, I probably start by asking you a few clarifying questions. Quantum Computation & Information is a broad field. I would say that it can primarily be viewed as a spectrum, similar to classical computing, from hardware up to algorithms. To get an idea of the hardware side, a great reference is [Jerry Chow's thesis](https://rsl.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/RSL_Theses/jmcthesis.pdf). This paper is a great overview of the hardware implementation that is popular today, superconducting qubits. There are different implementations of quantum computers today, but the superconducting qubit architecture is the most popular (for the time being). On the upper end of algorithms, there are several papers from the 1990's by Peter Shor and John Preskill that would be useful. Shor devised the quantum algorithm for prime factorization that you may have heard a lot about, and both Shor and Preskill were influential in the development of Quantum Error Correction, the idea that with enough qubits that are of good enough quality, you can implement error correcting codes and get quantum computers to perform arbitrarily well. In the middle, I would say that you have programming of today's (primarily IBM's) quantum computers for near term applications. This programming is primarily done in python using [qiskit](https://qiskit.org/), a programming framework made by IBM. A general reference for the whole field would be [Nielsen and Chuang's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107002176) on the subject as a whole. Hopefully this is good enough to get you started. Let me know if you would like more detail/references on a certain area.

Disclaimer: I have only been reading into quantum computing for about a year and half now, and certainly would not consider myself an expert.